# How do I insert arrows into a picture in GIMP?

Tags: gimp

I'd like to insert perfect arrows (the sort you can make using Inkscape: straight, symmetric tips, of customizable width and length, *etc.*) into images in GIMP. At the moment the closest thing to this I can do is by holding down "shift" whilst using the PaintBrush tool which just creates straight lines (with no arrowheads).

Comment: There are a lot of [tutorials](http://gimpforums.com/thread-how-do-i-draw-arrows) on the net. Can you tell us something more about your efforts? Have you tried to draw a [path](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-using-paths.html) and [stroke](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-path-stroke.html) it?

Comment: [ArrowsCreator 0.3](http://gimpchat.com/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=11670) is decent plugin for arrows.  Works with gimp 2.8.14

Answer (score 9, accepted):

GIMP features no ready "shapes" tools, or the ability to easily create arrows. 
You have to draw then manually - either zooming in the head region and using click_shift to raw two straight lines for the head - or using the paths tool to start with, manually putting two segments to the head, and selecting "edit->stroke"  for the whole path.

The advantage of the second approach is being able to fine tune the arrow before the stroke or undo/adjust/stroke again.

Depending on the workflow, you could draw a nice, steady arrow in a separate image, then copy it and `edit->paste as new->brush` - then you'd have a nice arrow stamp, with customizable size and angle to use with the brush tool.

Answer (score 30):

There is a plugin:

Download [`arrow.scm`](https://web.archive.org/web/20160706183906/http://registry.gimp.org/node/20269) and save it to `/home/username/.gimp-2.8/scripts` (on a Linux system).

For example:

```
cd ~/.gimp-2.8/scripts
wget https://web.archive.org/web/20160708211721/http://registry.gimp.org/files/arrow.scm
```

Check your version numbers, naturally. Next time you start up Gimp, you should see an *Arrow* option under the *Tools* menu.

Find out more about how to use it on [maketecheasier.com](https://www.maketecheasier.com/draw-arrows-in-gimp/).

Comment: It is 2016 now... To draw arrows we have google, then go to stackexchange, to grab the code for console, to download a plugin. Cool.

Comment: Definitely. <likely sarcasm noted, and then...> In 1991 we pored over books, called people we knew, and some limited few had Internet access. It's so much faster to get a solution moving these days.

Comment: A modified version of the above script to support bended arrows: http://registry.gimp.org/node/28566

Comment: you can just refresh the plugins list without restarting gimp: filters/scriptfu/refresh

Comment: Holy hell those are some ugly arrows: http://registry.gimp.org/files/Description.png

Comment: (Turns out the plugin actually generates half decent looking arrows, I guess the developer just chose the most garish colors possible for his showcase image.)

Comment: How do you set the arrow width with this plugin? It's drawing gigantic arrows for me and I can't find a way to control it's thickness.

Comment: If you did install Gimp 2.10 through Snap you need to put the arrow.scm file into the folder ~/snap/gimp/current/.config/GIMP/2.10.

Comment: GIMP 2.8 ... I ended up just using power point to make the arrows.

Comment: 'arrow.scm' does not work with curved paths in 2.10

Answer (score 11):

For GIMP versions later than 2.8:

1. Go to your home folder
2. Go to `.config/GIMP`
3. Go to the folder with a version number (`2.10` for me)
4. Go to `scripts`
5. [Download the arrow.scm](https://web.archive.org/web/20180208191139/http://registry.gimp.org:80/node/28566) file and place it here. Don't forget to unzip.
6. Open GIMP and draw a path

[image]

7. From `Tools` menu, select `Arrow`

[image]

Comment: The download link works, my download says `arrow.zip           100%[===================>]` but the arrow,zip archive can't be unzipped.

Comment: I have just verified that the file can be unzipped on a second computer. Likely something needs fixing on your end @karel

Comment: I found the link at http://www.programmer97.talktalk.net/Files/arrow.zip

Comment: The download is indeed not working. You'll have to go the the 2016 version on archive.org, or use this link: https://web.archive.org/web/20160420142436/http://www.programmer97.talktalk.net/Files/arrow.zip

Answer (score 5):

Use the text tool and copy & paste a unicode arrow sign

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrows_(Unicode_block)

Comment: With the obvious drawback that they do not have "customizable width and length", as was asked.

Comment: This is a great answer -- type an arrow using an enormous font size, than scale and rotate the layer to your liking

Answer (score 4):

This answer is based on [@User's comment](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/44797/how-do-i-insert-arrows-into-a-picture-in-gimp/64267#comment72803_44797).

One method of creating arrows in Gimp is to use the python plugin **ArrowsCreator**. A new version has been released (0.3) that works with Gimp versions 2.8.14 and above. 
To get it to work, download ArrowsCreator-0.3.py from http://gimpchat.com/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=11670 then place it in your gimp plugins folder as shown below (Windows 10).
[image: install gimp py location]

If Gimp is open, close it then restart it. You should get a popup box like the one shown below.
[image: Arrow Creator popup on install]

The first two entries are for creating a menu for this plugin. I changed "Arrows crea_tor" to "Arrows creator" then clicked OK.

Now open a picture in Gimp and click on **Extension->Plugins-Python->Tools-> Arrows Creator** as shown in the picture below.
[image: Arrow Creator Menu]

You should see some instructions showing you how to create arrows.
[image: Arrow Creator gimp python plugin instructions]

As instructed choose a color (I chose red).

[image: Select a color]

Then choose the path tool and click on the image twice (the points will become the head and tail of the arrow).

[image: Select path tool Gimp]

Choose your arrow style. I chose "Square cut shaft" style and got this

[image: Resulting arrow]

There are currently 7 different styles to choose from and customize. Hopefully this is enough information to get you started!

Comment: Thanks, but how do you use it in Gimp 2.10? I've put the plugin into `~/snap/gimp/40/.config/GIMP/2.10/plug-ins/`, but I'm not getting the initial window and there is no "Extensions" menu.

Comment: I’m guessing you are using linux? I’m not sure as I was using win10. Also, I’ve heard that Gimp 2.10 has broken a few plugins. I expect this could be one of them. If I get a chance to test it, I will update the post.